# Understanding RedHat / JBOSS fuse ESB

Tags: jboss, redhat, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I am trying to learn Redhat fuse ESB , I am new here but having prior experience in other ESB tools. I have some very basic question before starting ...

1) Is JBOSS fuse and RedHat fuse is same thing?
2) Is "Red Hat Developer Studio " is UI based development for both JBOSS and redhat fuse?
3) Is "Red Hat Developer Studio " Drag & drop UI application ? Where can I find some basic example for local development. I have tried going through https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/hello-world/#fndtn-windows but it didn't help ver well as here deployment happen in some cloud hosted server.

Answer (score 1):

1) Red Hat Fuse is the newer version of JBoss Fuse. JBoss Fuse is for Fuse 6.x, Red Hat Fuse is for Fuse 7.x

2) Yes, Red Hat Developer Studio which is including Fuse Tooling is providing UI tooling for both versions.

3) Yes, Red Hat Developer Studio is providing Drag & Drop UI. it is providing DnD for Camel XML DSl. If you want to use Camel Java DSL, there is no DnD but there is still some helper for deployment and to bootstrap a project.

For Local development, there are several possibilities:
- install an OpenShift instance (using minishift or Container Development Kit)
- use right-click -> Run as local camel context
- use a Fuse server adapter

Here is a tutorial https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.2/html/tooling_tutorials

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Aurelien . Can you please help in understanding Camel XML & Java DSL. In one ESB server ideally there should be only one DSL or can be mix. Which one is the best to start with.

is "Red Hat Developer Studio" coming with JBoss server itself or I need to install server separately and then run ESB service developed using Studio in that server?

Comment: There is an article here which discusses the XML vs Java DSL in Apache Camel: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/12/21/camel-dsl-choose/